# GitLab 403 error after disabling nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab

I have an omnibus package installation of `GitLab` on my web server.

I disabled nginx in the gitlab.rb using `nginx['enable'] = false` because I wanted to create multiple servers reachable by multiple subdomains.

The problem now is whenever I call my GitLab in the browser, it gets a 403 forbidden error.

Since this is a permission error, I expected to maybe use the wrong user here, but I also added `web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']` in the gitlab.rb file and double checked nginx's config file – the user is called 'www-data' as usual.

Have a look at my full config file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And here is my server configuration:

```
server {
        server_name gitlab.example.com;

        root /var/opt/gitlab;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Note: [Using an existing Passenger/Nginx installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-an-existing-passenger-nginx-installation) does mention you need to disable the built-in Nginx *and* Unicorn:

```
# Disable the built-in unicorn
unicorn['enable'] = false
```

> Make sure you run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the changes to take effect.

[Issue 692](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/692) also mentions:

> I compiled nginx with passenger support.
>   I installed passenger : `yum install passenger`.
>   I add the server block to a `vhost` file as instructed.
>   But it's not working till I see how to proper install passenger onto nginx:
>
> Refer to [2.3.3 of this page](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#inserting_passenger_root_for_apt)
>
> Open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and put `passenger_root /path-to-locations.ini;` under the `http` section
>
> The real path is the output of `passenger-config --root`
>
> Restart the nginx server and it should work (for me).

Warning:

> I had different versions between my `ruby` and `passenger_ruby` after a fresh GitLab migration on a new server.
>   I had to change my ruby version and then install passenger again in order to correct this problem.

Comment: I disabled unicorn (and set the `gitlab_rails['internal_api_url']` to the same url as my `esternal_url` to fit the example from your link) as well. No changes after reconfiguring and restarting GitLab though. And I don't use passenger for now. Is this a must to make it work? It didn't look like that for me until now.

Comment: @Froxx Yes, the documentation explicitly mentions passenger as a root cause for 403 error message.

Comment: Alright, I installed passenger with `apt-get` and updated my nginx.conf. I also updated my server configuration file as described in the docs. Now, when i try to start nginx, it errors: `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17`. Do I need to set additional passanger variables to make this work?

Comment: @Froxx My answer clearly mentions to compile nginx with the passenger module included. Do you have such an nginx?

Comment: Tbh, I'm not sure. I'm new to nginx and installed it simply with `apt-get install nginx`. How can check, if I have the module included?